# Антивирусник ругается на программу

Tags: c#, email, smtp-server

Пишу простой почтовый месседжер с возможностью отложенной отправки. Однако когда наступает момент отправлять письмо по адресу антивирус выдает `одна из программ ведет себя странно` и предлагает программу пофиксить. С одной стороны ничего страшного - всегда можно отказаться, но каждый раз закрывать диалоговое окно тоже надоедает. Вот код в момент исполнения которого avast видит угрозу. Причем сам exe многократно им проверен и одобрен.

```
    private static void send()
    {

            var mail = new MailMessage();
            var smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru");
            smtpServer.Port = 465;
            smtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("name@mail.ru", "pass");
            smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;               
            mail.Body = text;
            mail.From = new MailAddress("name@mail.r");
            mail.To.Add("goto@mail.ru");
            mail.Subject = "Test";
            smtpServer.Send(mail);
    }
```

Пробовал разные порты но результат тот же.

Comment: А вопрос то в чем?

Comment: Для Avast это нормальное поведение, он часто режет вполне себе честные программы, иногда даже не спрашивая, всякую криптографию например, как отечественную, так и зарубежную. Вы можете добавить вашу программу в список исключений антивируса, теоретически должно помочь, но это ж аваст...

Comment: Откажитесь от использования аваста, есть бесплатные решения получше. Он делает совершенно непростительные вещи - останавливает подозрительную программу и перезапускает ее, а что если эта программа - какой-нибудь прошивальщик, это может убить прошиваемую железку.

Comment: @rdorn была ситуация когда аваст заругался на dll с одним единственным методом `int z(int x, int y) {return x+y}` только пользователи этого не знают, они не видят исходного кода а только результат - **подозрительная программа** поэтому желательно подобной ситуации не допустить. Что ему могло не понравиться ?

Comment: @Андрей я могу его вообще отключить или удалить но вот пользователи (часть которых купили лицуху аваста) на такой шаг вряд ли пойдут. Мне нужно понять что ему не нравиться в этом участке кода и как это исправить.

Comment: Пробуйте комментировать строку / группы  строк (заведомо делая неполноценную программу) для "теста аваста" возможно так получится понять какая строка или комбинация строк ему не нравится. Возможно нужно переставить строки местами. А может он "открытие сокета" для отправки считает подозрительным, или отправку письма считает подозрительным (т.к. часть вирусов используют почту). Возможно попробуйте отправку реализовать через АctiveX (http://forum.oszone.net/thread-199309.html через CDO)

Comment: @nick_n_a  `smtpServer.Send(mail)` эта строчка ему не нравиться.

Comment: @nick_n_a Что такое CDO ?

Comment: Одна из mail-библиотек. Я ссылку (на ozone) дал с VBS примером.